# How to rename column names of Excel export file from WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, wpf

I have a WPF program that can export data from SQlite

```
ExportExcel = new RelayCommand(x =>
        {
            
            MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to export to Excel?", "Export to Excel", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
            if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            { 
                var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
            {
                Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx",
                Title = "Save an Excel File"
            };

            saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
            var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
            var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");

            for (int i = 0; i < _listCheckRecordModel.Count; i++)
            {
                int cellIndex = i + 1;
                worksheet.Cell("A" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Vender.VenderName;
                worksheet.Cell("B" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].IssueDate;
                worksheet.Cell("C" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Amount;
                worksheet.Cell("D" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Drawer;
                worksheet.Cell("E" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].BankTemplate;
            }

            workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveFileDialog.FileName))
                workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName);
            }
        });
```

But when it exports, it comes like this:

[image]

I want to name column A as 'Vender Name', B as 'Date', C as 'Amount' and so on when the user exports from WPF to excel. I searched online, but I couldn't find any help. How can I go about doing it?

Thanks in advance))

Comment: Why don’t you add a row with your desired header?

Comment: Changing the columns will not be possible, IMHO. Imagine a formula eg. `=A1+B1` do you really want to force the necessity to write a formula eg. `=Vendor Name1+Date1`

Comment: Changing column name was not possible, so I went with putting the header on the first row.. Thanks a lot for your time, guys))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to rename excel column name. all you can do is to put header on the first row.

Try this, I don't know if it will work since i can't try it myself.

```
 ExportExcel = new RelayCommand(x =>
    {
        
        MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to export to Excel?", "Export to Excel", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Question);
        if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
        { 
            var saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog
        {
            Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx",
            Title = "Save an Excel File"
        };

        saveFileDialog.ShowDialog();
        var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");

            worksheet.Cell("A" + 1).Value = "Vender Name";
            worksheet.Cell("B" + 1).Value = "Date";
            worksheet.Cell("C" + 1).Value = "Amount";
            worksheet.Cell("D" + 1).Value = "Drawer";
            worksheet.Cell("E" + 1).Value = "BankTemplate";
        
        int cellIndex = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < _listCheckRecordModel.Count; i++)
        { 
            worksheet.Cell("A" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Vender.VenderName;
            worksheet.Cell("B" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].IssueDate;
            worksheet.Cell("C" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Amount;
            worksheet.Cell("D" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].Drawer;
            worksheet.Cell("E" + cellIndex).Value = _listCheckRecordModel[i].BankTemplate;
        cellIndex++;
        }

        workbook.SaveAs("HelloWorld.xlsx");
        if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(saveFileDialog.FileName))
            workbook.SaveAs(saveFileDialog.FileName);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I did some digging, and changing column name was not possible, so I went with this. Thanks a lot! Appreciate the help))